# How do I modify the template that reference.cs is generated from?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, t4

I've been searching on the web for this, and maybe I'm just using the wrong keywords or something? I could use some help.

My problem is simple - we have a bunch of reference.cs files in our solution, which were auto-generated by VS2010 when adding services. These files don't add XML comments by default, so when we build the project, I get 800 or so messages in the build list. This doesn't break anything, but it does make the build take (significantly) longer, and mucks up the output screen.

I "fixed" this by adding the appropriate #pragma statments to the beginning and end of each reference.cs file, but if those ever get regenerated, they will have to be re-added by hand. I'd like to streamline that process and just add them to whatever T4 template VS2010 is using in the first place. The problem is, I don't know where that is, or if VS2010 is using something else to build these files?

Can this be done? Is there a better solution? I don't necessarily want to turn off XML comments for the entire project.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio does not use T4 templates to generate the service reference proxy classes (Reference.cs). Instead Visual Studio is most likely using the WsdlImporter and ServiceContractGenerator classes to generate this code.

There is a [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639156/make-svcutil-pick-up-documentation-from-c-sharp-files) on using either a [custom wsdl exporter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717040.aspx) or [WCFExtras](http://wcfextras.codeplex.com/) to add xml comments to the generated code. Both of these assume you have access to the code for the services you are referencing.