# Visual Studio: auto documentation for generated code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf

how can I generate a template with documentaton (doxygen) for auto-generated code?

To be more precisly: I'm using several connected services in my C# application.
Thus Visual studio generates some files including "Reference.cs" with a wrapper class to the methods of a WCF service.

Now I'm generating doxygen documentation for my entire project and get blank namespace and class documentation.

e.g.

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     Dieser Code wurde von einem Tool generiert.
//     Laufzeitversion:4.0.30319.42000
//
//     Änderungen an dieser Datei können falsches Verhalten verursachen und gehen verloren, wenn
//     der Code erneut generiert wird.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/// COMMENT NEEDED
namespace MyApp.ActionService {
[...]   

/// COMMENT NEEDED
public interface IActionsService {

[...]

/// COMMENT NEEDED
public partial class ActionsServiceClient : [...]
```

What I need is a general doxygen comment such as "autogenerated class" in every COMMENT NEEDED section of my code snippet. Note: I added the COMMENT NEEDED comments just to illustrate my problem. They are not part of the generator output.

Is it possible to  edit a template for the code generator?

Comment: Can't you exclude the generated classes from the documentation being generated? That would be easier then to add useless comments in a template.

Comment: I thought about that. But the documentation is part of a delivery to my customer. So he might think there is documentation missing for several classes as he doesn't know the code is autogenerated.

Comment: Why not just substitute _"COMMENT NEEDED"_ with _"autogenerated class"_ by your generator in the first place?

Comment: // The COMMENT NEEDED is not part of the generator output. I added them manually to the SO example to illustrate which comments I need. In generated code there is not such comment (unlikely)

Comment: You could make a program that could do this in 30 minutes

Answer (score 1):

It appears VS does not use editable T4 templates to generate proxy classes as in other auto-gen senarios. You may be able to use a tool built against svutil for this.

[Custom WSDL Publication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/custom-wsdl-publication)

[Make svcutil pick up documentation from C# files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639156/make-svcutil-pick-up-documentation-from-c-sharp-files)